# Using UI Controls in BackgroundWorker?

Tags: windows-phone-7, user-interface, backgroundworker

I'm currently making a Reading App for WP7. To make it a little bit original, I decided to wrap the text in a Panorama Control, to imitate the "flipping page" movement with the thumb.

I created several method to put enough but not too much text in every panel of the panorama, and creating more panels if necessary. The main method goes like this (in verbal form) :

```
split the string on spaces, giving a string array containing words.

foreach(word)
    add word in the textBlock of the current "page"
    if the textBlock's height is over the maximum height allowed
        remove the word
        create a new page (aka new panoram item with a new textBlock)
        make this new page the current one
        add the word in the new textBlock
    endif
endforeach
```

As you can guess, this method is quite time-consuming. It is called on the loading of the ApplicationPage, making it extremely long, according to the length of the string.

I've tried several things, like generate the two first pages on the loading, then generating on at a time when the users pans to read the next page, but even with this solution, the pan transition lags during the call of the method.

I've thought of the BackgroundWorker class to do the job, but unfortunately I've seen that it can't access the UI itself, and even if it could, I'm afraid that it would block the UI thread or at least making it lag.

I "like" this method because it formats the text independently of the size of the font or event the font used, unlike my previous tests where I used a fixed number of characters per page (like 700 characters max, but 700 "i" doesn't make the same height and width that 700 "m").

So maybe you have an other solution for this problem. I'm not specifically asking for a chunk of code to copy and paste in my project. As I'm actually learning C# with this project, I aim to code it fully by myself.

Thank you for reading it, and sorry for the potential grammar or vocabulary mistakes, as English isn't my mother tongue.

Friendly,

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Well for now we can consider that this is this one : Can we use UI controls the way I use it in my current method (meaning that the events reportprogress or completed are useless) in a BackgroundWorker without making the UI unresponsive ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the UI changes through Dispatcher.BeginInvoke call.

Other than that and the progress reporting and when the background worker is completely done, I don't think there's much you can do.

Controls are created on UI thread and therefore accessible only from there or through the mechanisms I mentioned.